# How to get the time information of the files after find | grep keyword command?

Tags: linux, grep, find

Now I know how to use find | grep keyword to get the file I want.

But after that, how should I know the size, create_time info of each file I found?

For example, after find | grep tutorial, I got this:

```
./lab/zengjuchen/tutorial
./lab/zengjuchen/tutorial/tutorial
```

How should I view their creating time and size?

Comment: Are you searching filename or inside file with grep? You question says filename. If this is correct, then @slhck's answer covers it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started off wrong by using `find` and `grep` together. `find` is perfectly capable of filtering files. You don't need `grep` for it—in fact, shuffling around file names like this is not recommended.

Do this instead:

```
find -name '*tutorial*' -exec <some-command> {} \;
```

Here, `<some-command>` will be run for every file found, whose name will replace `{}`. For example, to get the file size:

```
find -name '*tutorial*' -exec du {} \;
```

Using `\+` instead of `\;` will make `find` execute the command on all files at once, if the given command supports passing more than one file argument. This will speed up the process.

---

Or you could even just do it with Bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
du **/*tutorial*
```

Here, `**` recursively traverses all directories.

---

As for creation time: Traditionally, this is not stored. You'll only get the last access, modified and status change time. See more about [`stat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(Unix)). File systems such as `ext4` do store the creation time as "Birth Time". So, `stat -c %w` would work for those. Read more about this issue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91197/5893).

Comment: And to elaborate on this the "-ls" option of find gives you an ls like output which might already show you what you need.  And if that doesn't work an alternative to find ... -exec is to use xargs.  The advantage of xargs is that the results of find are passed to a single instance of the command which is often better for performance. Example: find ./ -name '*tutorial*' -print0 | xargs -0 du

Comment: @Bram `xargs` does the same as `find [...] -exec [...] {} +`, which is [POSIX compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html#tag_04_55_05). And [`-0` is not POSIX compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xargs.html).